# Passport Local Strategy - not pass callback

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local, passport-facebook

I think I created a standard passport local strategy as many people did before. I had parsed the form, tried `enctype = "multipart/urlencoded"`, that most of the ways people mentioned. However, `passport.serializeUser` is still never been triggered.

It can now redirect to home page, however, when console the user, it is undefined.

```js
const env = require('dotenv').load(),
config = require( __dirname + '/config.json' )[process.env.NODE_ENV],
config_web = config.web,

config_fb = config.fb,
_WEB_PORT = config_web.port,
_WEB_HOST = config_web.host,
_FB_ID = config_fb.fid,
_FB_SECRET = config_fb.secret;

const express = require('express'),
app = express(),
compression = require('compression'),
ejs = require('ejs'),
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
fs = require('fs'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
csrf = require('csurf'),
csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true }),
parseForm = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }),
methodOverride = require('method-override'),
randomstring = require("randomstring"),
_DB = require('./db');
moment = require('moment-timezone'),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
FB = require('fb'), fb = new FB.Facebook(),//(options)
request = require('request-promise'),
passport = require('passport'), 
fb_Strategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy, 
local_Strategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
morgan = require('morgan'),
expresssession = require('express-session'),
connectensurelogin = require('connect-ensure-login'),
flash = require('connect-flash'),
bcrypt = require('bcrypt'),
timezone = 'Asia/Hong_Kong';

app.use(flash());
app.use(compression());
app.use(cookieParser());
//app.disable('view cache');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + "/views");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); //, { maxAge: oneDay }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));

//app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(expresssession({ 
  secret: 'keyboard cat', 
  resave: false, 
  saveUninitialized: false, 
  cookie: { maxAge: 3600000 } 
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
  console.log("user");
  console.log(user);
  cb(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, cb) {
  console.log("obj");
  console.log(obj.id);
  
  let select = "SELECT * from user where login_id = '" + obj.id + "' and login_type = '" + obj.type+ "'";
  _DB.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
      if (err){
        console.log("err");
      }else{
        connection.query( select, function(err, result) {
            if(result.length>0){
              return cb(null, { name: result[0].name, id: result[0].login_id, login_type: result[0].login_type, accessToken: result[0].token});
            }
            connection.release();
        });
        
      }
  });

});

passport.use('local',new local_Strategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'//,
    //passReqToCallback : true
  },
  function(username, password, done) {
    console.log("local_Strategy");
    let getPwd = "SELECT login_pw FROM user WHERE login_id = '" + username + "' and login_type = 'direct'";
    _DB.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err){
          return done(err);
        }else{
          connection.query( getPwd, function(err, result) {
              if( result.length > 0 ){
                let checkPwd =  bcrypt.compareSync(password, result[0].login_pw);
                if(checkPwd){
                  return done(null, {type: "direct", id: username});
                }else{
                  return done(null, false);
                }
              }else{
                return done(null, false);
              }
              connection.release();
          });
          
        }
    });
  }
));

passport.use('facebook',new fb_Strategy({
    clientID: _FB_ID,
    clientSecret: _FB_SECRET,
    callbackURL: `http://${_WEB_HOST}:${_WEB_PORT}/login/facebook/return`
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    console.log("fb_Strategy"); 

    let checkExist = "SELECT token FROM user WHERE login_id = '" + profile.id + "' and login_type = '" + profile.provider + "'";
    let insertNew = "INSERT INTO user (name, email, login_type, login_id, token) values ('" + profile.displayName + "','" + profile.email  +"','" + profile.provider +"','" + profile.id +"', '" + accessToken + "')";
    let update = "UPDATE user SET token = '" + accessToken + "' WHERE login_id = '" + profile.id + "' and login_type = '" + profile.provider + "'";
    
    _DB.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err){

        }else{
          connection.query( checkExist, function(err, result) {
              if(result.length>0){
                if(result[0].token == accessToken){
                  connection.query( update, function(err, result2) {
                  });
                }

              }else{
                connection.query( insertNew, function(err, result3) {
                });
              }
              connection.release();
              return cb(null, {type: profile.provider, id: profile.id});
          });
          
        }
    });
}));

// app.post('/login',  function(req, res, next){
//   passport.authenticate('local',{
//       //successRedirect: '/',
//       //failureRedirect: '/logout?status=login failed',
//       failureFlash: true 
//   }, function(err, user, info){
//     console.log(user);
//           if(err){
//               //return next(err);
//           }
//           if(!user){
//               req.flash('login', 'Failed!')
//               return res.redirect('/login/direct');
//           }

//           res.redirect('/');
//       }
//   )(req, res, next);
// }
// );


app.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local',{
      successRedirect: '/',
      failureRedirect: '/login/direct',//'/logout?status=login failed',
      failureFlash: true 
  }), function(err, user, info){
    console.log(err);
    console.log(user);
    console.log(info);
          if(err){
              //return next(err);
          }
          if(!user){
              req.flash('login', 'Failed!')
              //return res.redirect('/login/direct');
          }

          //res.redirect('/');
  });

app.post('/register', parseForm, csrfProtection, function(req, res){

  let c_password = req.body.c_password;
  let email = req.body.email;
  let type = "direct";

  //res.send('data is being processed')
  let checkExist = "SELECT id FROM user WHERE email = '" + email + "' and login_type = '" + type + "'";
  let insertNew = "INSERT INTO user (name, email, login_type, login_id, login_pw) values ('" + email + "','" + email  +"','" + type +"', '" + email  +"','" + bcrypt.hashSync(c_password, 10) + "')";
  //let update = "UPDATE user SET token = '" + accessToken + "' WHERE login_id = '" + profile.id + "' and login_type = '" + type + "'";
  
  _DB.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
      if (err){

      }else{
        connection.query( checkExist, function(err, result) {
            if(result.length>0){
              // if(result[0].token == accessToken){
              //   connection.query( update, function(err, result2) {
              //   });
              // }
              req.flash('register', 'Exist!')
              res.redirect('/register');

            }else{
              connection.query( insertNew, function(err, result3) {
                req.flash('register', 'OK!')
                res.redirect('/login/direct');
              });
            }
            connection.release();
            //return cb(null, {type: type, id: email});
        });
        
      }
  });


});

const now = moment.tz(timezone).format(),
date1 = moment.tz("2017-10-30 17:02", timezone).format(), 
date2 = moment.tz("2017-10-27 15:59", timezone).format(), 
date3 = moment.tz("2017-10-28 15:59", timezone).format();

if( now >= date1 ){
    //console.log('larger');
}else{
    //console.log('smaller');
}

app.get('/',
function(req, res) {
  console.log("Home");
  console.log(req.user );
  res.render('index', { user: req.user });
});

app.get('/login',
function(req, res){
    if(req.user){
      res.redirect('/');
    }else{
      res.render('login');
    }
  
});

app.get('/login/facebook',  
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        scope: ['user_tagged_places', 'user_photos']
    }
));

app.get('/login/direct', csrfProtection,  function(req, res){
  res.render('login_email',{
      csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
      message: req.flash('login')
  });
});

app.get('/register', csrfProtection, function(req, res){
  res.render('reg',{
    csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
    message: req.flash('register')
  });
});

app.get('/login/facebook/return', 
passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/profile', connectensurelogin.ensureLoggedIn(),
function(req, res){
  res.render('profile', { user: req.user });
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
  });

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
res.status(404);
//res.send('Sorry cant find that!');
res.redirect('/');
//res.end();
})

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
if (err.code !== 'EBADCSRFTOKEN') return next(err)

// handle CSRF token errors here
res.status(403)
res.send('Error.')
})

function isValidKey(key) {
var re = /((\.)|(\$)|(#)|(\[)|(\]))/;
return re.test( key );
}

server.listen(_WEB_PORT, function(){
    console.log(`Listening on port http://${_WEB_HOST}:${_WEB_PORT}/`);
});
```